# VBA : export both sheets and graph objects into one PDF file

Tags: vba, pdf, charts, export, spreadsheet

I have a workbook with several sheets with data, which I'd like to export as PDF. That step is pretty simple to achieve with the following code :

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()
Dim FolderPath As String

FolderPath = "C:\Output_folder"

Sheets(Array(1, 2)).Select

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & "\Test", _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

However, to this export I would also like to add a chart object which is in another sheet, let's say sheet 3 (only the chart object, not the whole sheet).

I have tried adding the chart to the selection, right after `Sheets(Array1,2)).Select` :

```
Sheets(3).ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
```

But obviously this does not work and the PDF now only contains the chart object without the content of the sheets 1 & 2.

How should I proceed to export into one PDF both the content of sheets and a specific chart object ?

Many thanks for your inputs. I couldn't find any related question that mixes two types of objects (sheet and charts) for one export.

Kind regards

Comment: Set the print area of the sheet with the chart to fit only the range covered by the chart, and turn off the gridlines.  You can record a macro while doing that to see the syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, the chart is very likely to be moved by users and that seems more problematic than programmatically aiming at the chart object itself and printing it along with other sheets... of course if this is something doable...

Comment: If the chart is on a worksheet then I don't think you can select it separately from the worksheet.   You could determine its position and size using VBA and set the print area accordingly.